# WPF Animation Clock not doing anything?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, user-interface

I have the following code:

```
private void UserControl_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    FadingBox.ApplyAnimationClock(Border.OpacityProperty, OverClock);
}
private void UserControl_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OverAnime = new DoubleAnimation(FadingBox.Opacity, 90, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1600));
    OverClock = OverAnime.CreateClock();
}
```

this is the code for when you hover over a button, it lights up (by fading and becoming less transparent). I also have nearly identical code for when you leave off of the button, it goes back to normal. The only problem--it does nothing. I put in a breakpoint on it, and it wasn't set to null, I tried using `BeginAnimation()` instead, that doesn't fade correctly, I looked it up online and I can't figure out why it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I feel really stupid, turns out my only problem was that I was trying to set the opacity to 100 for fully opaque, when it's supposed to be 1.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using an `EventTrigger`. Here is an example in XAML to achieve the fade-in/fade-out effect:

```
    <Button Content="OK" Height="46" Width="98">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="1.0" To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="0.5" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>         
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

**EDIT:**
The problem with your code is that you're starting the `AnimationClock` as soon as the control is loaded. You have to start the clock when the mouse enters the button. I still think you should try to set the animation in XAML if you can, but here is the solution to your specific problem. You don't have to do anything in the `Load` event:

```
    void btn_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {   
        DoubleAnimation animation = 
            new DoubleAnimation(1.0, 0.5, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5)));
        btn.ApplyAnimationClock(Button.OpacityProperty, animation.CreateClock());       
    }
```